# PATH_INFO missing on nginx + apache2 proxy pass setup

Tags: nginx, perl

I'm trying to work out why `$ENV{PATH_INFO}` is empty in a Perl script on my new server. This is my nginx configuration:

```
    location ~ \.cgi$ {
        try_files $uri =404;
        gzip off;
        proxy_set_header X-Real-IP  $remote_addr;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $remote_addr;
        proxy_set_header Host $host;
        proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:8181;
    }
```

I have also tried adding:

```
proxy_set_header PATH_INFO  $fastcgi_path_info;
```

but that doesn't seem to make a difference. Is there something else I need to do?

Software versions:

- nginx version: nginx/1.13.4
- This is perl 5, version 22, subversion 1 (v5.22.1)
- Server version: Apache/2.4.18 (Ubuntu)

Comment: A header is not an environment variable.  See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8098927/nginx-variables-similar-to-setenv-in-apache for more how to do this in nginx.

Comment: @chicks thanks. Am I missing something though., How do you do this on a proxy_pass? I need to pass it  to Apache so we can use mod_perl, but when I've looked into doing this with fastcgi it doesn't work.